# Java: Processing multiple .xlsx files using Apache POI

Tags: java

How to read multiple xlsx files using apache poi jar.?
I'm using apache version 3.10.It's working if I read one .xlsx file. As I'm running a job to handle files in a thread,I'll get more than one file to process. But I'm unable to rectify where to change it inorder to make it work for multiple file processing.?

Answer (score 1):

```
private class Thread1 extends Thread {
            public Thread1(File file) {
                this.file = file;
            }

            File file;

            public void run() {
                readFromFiles(this.file);
            }

            public void readFromFiles(File file) {
                try {
                    File folder = new File("/folderpath");
                    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                    for (File file1 : listOfFiles) {

                        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(file);

                        String fileName = file1.getName();
```

XSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input_document);
                        }

```
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            public static void main(String[] args1) {

                File folder = new File("/folderpath");
                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                Test t=new Test();
                for (File file1 : listOfFiles) {        
                    Thread1 thread=new Thread1(file1);
                    thread.start();
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but the question seems that due to multiple threads processing xls files at the same time goes wrong; change the same data. An answer would be to only use local variables, new objects, do not use fields. Hence this particular answer might seem irrelevant. Though I like seeing code. Keep on the works.